# Wordpress cannot modify header info. Unable to export database to a CSV file

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, wordpress

Ok, I'm trying to export a table in my MySql database and I keep getting this error, what could be the problem? I really want to get this working, if someone could give ,e any advice or any answers that would be great! Search all over the web and unable to find anything.
*Keep in mind* I'm using wordpress, php, ajax, and jQuery
Thanks!

```
    <?php 
header("Content-Type: application/csv");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment;Filename=report.csv");
```

**Error:** `Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent`

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: This = Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

White characters get in output before PHP sets the headers. The headers ***have to*** go first.

Make sure you remove any spaces, tabs, new lines, etc. from before and in-between the `<?PHP` and the actual php code.

```
<?php 
header("Content-Type: application/csv");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment;Filename=report.csv");
...
```

Comment: Thanks for your answers, I'm getting output but i'm still getting 2 of the same header errors.

Comment: Is this code `include`d or `require`d? You may want to "debug it" and kill it before it attempts to set headers to see if anything has been sent to browser by then. This may help you identify the nasty output.

Comment: I found out it's clashing with headers in wp-admin/admin-header.php ? I removed the 2 headers in my code and now there is no error and it's outputting the table rows I want now, but still don't know if this is correct?

Comment: I wouldn't know about wordpress or its internal framework. Your code doesn't look like a formal plugin though so I'd say... it works, doesn't it? ;)